# Xamarin Android Native: Cannot get MvvmCross Color plugin to work

Tags: android, xamarin, data-binding, mvvmcross

I have a MvxListView with custom template defined. The binding in general works well. I see labels bound. However not BackgroundColor property when binding:

```
        <LinearLayout
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              local:MvxBind="Text Name;BackgroundColor 
              NativeColor(HexColor(Color))">
```

The `Color` property I tried to have as stringn as 
This is the most "sophisticated" version I tried the last (HexColor is my custom ValueConverter). As there was like 20 different ones before and none of them worked. Color is I tried `Color(Color)` and NativeColor(Color) (accordingly to [this](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/color)), and without the Converter, and `background`, `Background`, `backgroundColor`, but nothing helps.
I also checked and it looks like the plugin is setup well for Color.

So, any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order the Color plugin to work make sure you have the Bootstrap class `ColorPluginBootstrap` in the `Bootstrap` folder of your native project:

```
using MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins;

namespace MyProject.Mobile.Droid.Bootstrap
{
    public class ColorPluginBootstrap
        : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<MvvmCross.Plugins.Color.PluginLoader>
    {
    }
}
```

If you have that setup correctly then you can make your own color converters based on `MvxColorValueConverter<T>`, e.g.:

```
public class BooleanToBicolorConverter : MvxColorValueConverter<bool>
{
    protected override MvxColor Convert (bool value, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // returns gray or white depending whether value is true or false.
        return value ? new MvxColor (215, 215, 215) : new MvxColor (255, 255, 255);
    }
}
```

And you use that like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    local:MvxBind="Text Name; BackgroundColor BooleanToBicolor(MyBoolProperty)">
```

If you want to just bind an `MvxColor` of your ViewModel to your View you can use [MvxNativeColorValueConverter](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross.Plugins/Color/MvxNativeColorValueConverter.cs) like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    local:MvxBind="Text Name; BackgroundColor NativeColor(MyMvxColorProperty)">
```

You can find the other Mvx base color converters [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/MvvmCross.Plugins/Color)

HIH

Comment: Hi! So, this is the core of my question actually. I already use `BackgroundColor NativeColor(MyMvxColorProperty)`, but it doesn't work for me. Does the NativeColor converter exist out of the box, or this is what I have to create myself? (And yes, I surely have `MvxPluginBootstrapAction` installed).

Comment: It should work out of the box, check the output for any message/warning/error mvx is throwing using that binding with that converter and even though it is obvious check that the colour you are binding is not the same colour as the background of your parent view. BTW which version of mvx are you using?